# Error:Not able to login using through login API that I have developed

Tags: node.js

I have created an authentication API in node and where the password are encrypted using CryptoJS. But now I am not able to login with the username and password which I have added to the mongodb database through RegisterApi. When I tested the login API through postman, it returns an error of “user not found”. The code to my login API is given below.

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const { route } = require("./users");
//LOGIN
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
try {
const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
if (!user){
return res.status(401).json("User not found"); }
const hashedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
user.password,
process.env.PASS_SEC
    );
const password = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
if(password !=req.body.password){
res.status(401).json("Wrong credentials!");
   }
res.status(200).json(user)
console.log(user)
  } catch (err) {
res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Have you tried logging req.body.username? What output does it give?

Comment: it gives user not found only.

Comment: I meant logging req.body.username, have you tried console.log(req.body.username) and see its output? If it is null or undefined, then it means the data is not passed into the route

Comment: It is showing undefined. Why is that so??

Comment: The way i did it was i exported the variable using export.variable='user' and then imported it into index.js/app.js by const {user} = './routes/auth.js'. and then console.log(user). Is this the correct way to do that??